# How to call method inside the same class in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, method-call

I want to call the method inside the same class. For example, when I click a button, it will trigger the method `handleLoginBtnClicked()`. I expect it will call the method `checkInputValidation()` in the same class. What is the proper way to do this?

```
export default class LoginCard extends React.Component {

    //If I click a button, this method will be called.
    handleLoginBtnClicked() {
        this.checkInputValidation();
    }

    checkInputValidation() {
        alert("clicked");
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        <LoginBtn onClick={this.handleLoginBtnClicked}/>
        ...
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.checkInputValidation is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to bind those functions to the context of the component. Inside `constructor` you will need to do this:

```
export default class LoginCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleLoginBtnClicked = this.handleLoginBtnClicked.bind(this);
        this.checkInputValidation = this.checkInputValidation.bind(this);
    }

    //This is the method handleLoginBtnClicked
    handleLoginBtnClicked() {
        ...
    }

    //This is the method checkInputValidation 
    checkInputValidation() {
        ...
    }

    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

Comment: Any reason you chose to not do this in the constructor?

Comment: @CasperLI This would be one of the best practices that there are. For more information you can follow [the link here](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Where are you binding the `handleLoginBtnClicked`? You may be losing the functions context and losing the meaning of the special variable `this`. React will handle and trigger the `onClick` event, calling the function from a different context which is why it has been lost.

You should use the following syntax to create a new bound function to add as the event listener for the onClick event. This will ensure that `handleLoginBtnClicked`'s context is not lost.

```
<element onClick={this.handleLoginBtnClicked.bind(this)}>
```